# Data modeling of entities with many-to-many relationship in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, many-to-many, data-modeling

How do we create a data model in Cassandra with two entities: Partner and Subscriber where one partner can have multiple subscribers and one subscriber can subscribe to many partners. We are dealing with potentially a big data, i.e 10 millions subscribers and hundreds of partners.

Most frequent queries would be:

1. Fetch all subscriber by their partner name
2. Fetch all subscribers by their partner name by certain state
3. Fetch all partners created after certain date/
4. Fetch partner that have specific number of subscribers

Since I'm novice in NoSQL world, I only can think of two approaches at the moment:

1. Create the partner_ids column in Subscriber table as a set of partner ids.
   So then query would be: SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIBERS WHERE <partner_id> IN partner_ids (I'm not sure about query performance here)
2. Create a third table PartnerSubscribe table where the partition key would be partner_name, and subscriber information as data columns. I know that denormalization is suggested for efficient querying, but in this case there will be a huge amount of duplicate data if there are a lot of subscribers subscribed to dozens of partners. If for instance, 2 partners has the same 6 million subscribers, the size of this table will unnecessarily grow.

**Question:**
**If one subscriber is subscribed to multiple partners, how should we handle the data modeling to efficiently carry out the queries from above?**

*Sorry for non-technical question. I just need a basic understanding of the data modeling in many-to-many relationships with potentially huge rows. Thank you in advance*

Comment: What is the Cassandra version that you're using? Is this Apache Cassandra or a DBaaS like fully-managed offering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General Principles**

Data Modelling with Cassandra is (very) different from relational. There are no joins, you need to go by denormalization. The data will be duplicated in profit for performance, it is expected, storage is cheap. (6 million rows is NOTHING).

There is a methodology described on DS220 academy.datastax.com for the data modeling but the first thing to understand quickly is most of the time you will have one table per query.

When you work with associations many-to-many you will need a minimum of 2 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscribers_by_partner (
   partner_id UUID, 
   subscriber_id UUID
   PRIMARY KEY ((partner_id), subscriber_id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partner_by_subscribers (
   subscriber_id UUID, 
   partner_id UUID
   PRIMARY KEY((subscriber_id), partner_id)
)
```

Now we can start thinking about the requests

**Query on Subscribers**

Luckily you can achieve `1` and `2` with the same table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscribers_by_partner (
 partner_id     UUID,
 state          text,
 subscriber_id  UUID
 PRIMARY KEY((partner_id), state, subscriber_id)
);
```

You can go then with

```sql
--- Fetch all subscribers by their partner name
SELECT * FROM subscribers_by_partner where partner_id=....

--- Fetch all subscribers by their partner name by certain state
SELECT * FROM subscribers_by_partner 
where partner_id=.... 
AND state=...
```

**Query on Partners**

- Fetch all partners created after a certain date

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partners_by_subscribers (
 subscriber_id  UUID,
 creation_date  DATE,
 partner_id    UUID,
 PRIMARY KEY((subscriber_id), creation_date, partner_id)
);
```

Here you can go with :

```sql
SELECT * FROM partners_by_subscribers 
WHERE subscriber_id=?
AND creation_date > ?
```

If you do no want to provide the subscriber id here it would be a full scan table, pretty bad. You can think of group by day or WEEK to make to not too ugly.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partners_by_date (
 yyyymmdd      TEXT,
 creation_date  DATE,
 partner_id    UUID,
 PRIMARY KEY((yyyymmdd), creation_date, partner_id)
);
```

- Fetch partners that have a specific number of subscribers

This is one is tricky the count(*) will timeout most of the time and cannot be applied everywhere. You can leverage counters but even then you need a full scan of the cluster to get all partner's information.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partner_stats (
 partner_id        UUID
 subscriber_count  counter,
 PRIMARY KEY((partner_id), state)
);
```

**More insights:**

> Create the partner_ids column in Subscriber table as a set of partner ids. So then query would be: SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIBERS WHERE <partner_id> IN partner_ids (I'm not sure about query performance here)

The IN clause behaves very poorly, next version of Cassandra will stop you at 18 items in clause with a guardrail as the load is reported to the coordinator of the request.

> a huge amount of duplicate data if there are a lot of subscribers subscribed to dozens of partners. If for instance, 2 partners has the same 6 million subscribers, the size of this table will unnecessarily grow.

In regards of Cassandra, that duplication is expected.

Comment: so it is suggested to create a table per query even though it might duplicate the whole table? If I have 10mln data, and 4 queries, I would have to create 4 tables with 40 mln records in order to efficiently perform the queries?

Comment: This is correct. It is the tradeoff. You can test to create secondary indices to evaluate performance but here I see a high cardinality (subscribers/partners)